# Mean of all rows exluding first column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I would like to add a Mean column to for every row, but excludes the first column 'Dept'.  So for example row 0 should have the 45.007000 instead of NaN.

```
df2 = df[MatchesWithDept].copy()
df2 = df2.replace(-999.250000, np.NaN)
df2 = df2.assign(Master_GR=df2.loc[:, Matches[:]].mean())


    DEPT        GRD  GRR  Master_GR
0  400.0  45.007000  NaN        NaN
1  400.5  42.575001  NaN        NaN
2  401.0  43.755001  NaN        NaN
3  401.5  45.417000  NaN        NaN
4  402.0  47.519001  NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) first column before [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html):

```
df['Master_GR'] = df.drop('DEPT', axis=1).mean(axis=1)
```

Or select all columns without first by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df['Master_GR'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].mean(axis=1)
```